# Want to manage SQL Server dynamically in c#

Tags: sql-server, database, nhibernate, metadata, smo

I want to manage SQL Server dynamically, that is through code I wan to scan SQL Server for available databases than I want to create new database, access older database, alter it, and insert data into database depending upon table schema what is better approach what should I use?

i heard name of nhibernate, SQL Server Management Object (SMO), Smss (SQL Server Management Studio) but i do not know more than their names

please guide me with pros and cons

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate is an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) which has no direct relation to SQL Server. SMSS is a GUI tool for managing SQL Server. SMO is what you need. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/smo.aspx), for example.

Comment: thank you for it but where should i start from to learn smo is there any tutorial

Comment: The link Anton gave you *is* a place to get started.  Also see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms162169.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

SMO is the way to go. You have detailed information [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).